# How to prove that $e^x = 8x^3$ has only one solution in $[0,1]$?

Tags: calculus

Prove that $e^x = 8x^3$ has only one solution in $[0,1]$.

If we define $f(x) = e^x - 8x^3$ then by mean value theorem there exists at least one solution. But $f$ is not strictly decreasing/increasing. How do I continue?

Comment: Find the turning point, and show that it is decreasing in the interval between that and 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = e^x - 8x^3.$ Then $f(0)f(1) = (e-8) < 0,$ so $f$ has at least one zero in $(0,1).$ Suppose $0 < a < 1$ is a zero of $f.$ Then (i) $e^a = 8a^3$ and $$(ii)\ \  f^\prime(a) = e^a - 24a^2 = 8a^3 - 24a^2 = 8a^2(a - 3) < 0.$$ That means  at a zero of $f$ in $(0,1)$ the slope of $f$ is negative. That implies $f$ can only have one zero in $(0,1).$

Comment: The $8a^2(1-3)$ should be $8a^2(a-3)$, but that does not change anything relevant. (+1)

Comment: @mickep, did i have it wrong first? anyway it is correct now.

Comment: Indeed, now it is fine.

Comment: @dragon, thanks doe the edit. can you please let me know next time and i will do the editing.

Comment: @abel Sure thing. In fact, I was about to fix your capitalization as well, but since you prefer to be notified about it instead, can you fix your capitalization?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is concave on $[0.1,1]$, so $f(0.1)>0$ and $f(1)<0$ imply that the root from $(0.1,1)$ is unique. To check that there is no root on $(0,0.1)$, note that $f'(x)$ is positive here and $f(0)>0$, $f(0.1)>0$.